# CSS: cannot get a fluid height working on a div

Tags: css

In my page I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="pentagon"> 
        <a href="http://webdesigncrowd.com/dribbble-application-icons/">
            <span class="mask"></span>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="width: 100%;">
        </a>
        <div class="portfolio-title">
             <h4>Dribbble's App Icons<span>View Project</span></h4> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.portfolio {
    text-align: center;
}
.portfolio .pentagon {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box; // is this really necessary?
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.portfolio .pentagon a {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;  //was 200px
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;  
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.portfolio .pentagon a img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -75px;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
         -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
            transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.portfolio .pentagon a span.mask {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/100/100") no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 350ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 350ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform 350ms ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform 350ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}

.portfolio .pentagon a img.hovering {
    left: -50px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
         -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.portfolio .pentagon a span.mask:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
            transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.pentagon .portfolio-title {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*  margin-top: 20px; */
}

.pentagon .portfolio-title h4 {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}

.portfolio-title h4 span {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    color: #4EA838;
    top: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CcALd/)

As you resize the "Result" window you can see that the div's width increases as do the images of the kittens.

The problem is that ".portfolio .pentagon a" in my CSS has a fixed height. I don't want that, but if I remove it or try to give it a height using percent it doesn't work. It just acts like the height is 0.

What I want is for ".portfolio .pentagon a" to take the height of either its containing image (the kitten in the background) or the background of ".portfolio .pentagon a span.mask" (the kitten in the foreground). *I know it sounds weird that the background should be in the foreground but in my actual design I'm using an image that's partially transparent.

I did some googling around and most of the answers pointed to using a clearfix. I wasn't able to wrap my head around that, but I did try applying it in different ways without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a clearfix is for floated contain. (That's not your case).

You can not adjust the size of the container to the image because it is absolute positioned. Just changing it to relative position should fix that.

```
.portfolio .pentagon a img {
    position: relative;
    left: -75px;
    ...
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CcALd/1/)

Comment: That was ridiculously easy. Thank you!

Comment: I guess that you were on the wrong track. Happy that it helped !